# I want to make a save as with file name as, time stamp(space)text in range M2(space)Design Format

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make a save as with file name as, time stamp(space)text in range M2(space)Design Format
example: 20200525 1747 Client Design Format
Range M2 = Client

```
Sub Make_saveas()

    Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & Format(Now(), 
        "YYYYMMDD HHMM, sheets(3).range("M2"), "Design Format"")& ".xlsx", 
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Please help me with the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

```
Filename:=Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\" & Format(Now(),"YYYYMMDD HHMM") & " " & sheets(3).range("M2") & " Design Format.xlsx"
```